# How to get only one value from database query?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I got a row from database table now I wish to echo only one value from this row in CakePHP.
So how to do it?

```
$help = $this->help->findByControllerAndAction($controller ,$action)
```

it has four values: `id`, `controller`, `action` and `help_text`.
I want to echo only `controller`.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading some of the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html), more specifically this [section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#create-a-posts-controller).

To answer your question...

I assume your Help model has a unique key controller+action.

In your controller's method you will need:

```
$help = $this->Help->findByControllerAndAction($controller ,$action);
if ($help) {
    $this->set('help', $help);
}
```

In your view:

```
echo $help['Help']['controller'];
```

will show the content of the Help.controller field.

Use:

```
debug($help);
```

If $help is not defined in your view, chances are your find is not returning the results you expect.

Comment: I edited my answer. debug() will help you check what's actually inside the variable.